# vim shortcut to go from command mode back to normal mode

Tags: vim, vimrc

I use **`nnoremap ; :`** to go to command mode.
Is there oposite shortcut that i can add to my .vimrc so that i won't press ESC every time to go back to normal mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aborting command-line mode shouldn't be so frequent, why do you worry about having to press <kbd>Esc</kbd>?!

Some people remap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to either <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (outside of Vim), this also helps with leaving insert mode. Did you know that you can also use Ctrl-C to abort the command-line? Alternatively, you can define a mapping, e.g. `;;` to abort the command-line:

```
:cnoremap ;; <C-c>
```

Answer (score 0):

Choose some easy-to-type key sequence that you aren't likely to use in any text and map it to <Esc>. The sequence `qq` is not found in English, for example, so you could map it like this:

```
inoremap qq <Esc>
```

If you ever have a need to enter that sequence into some file, just precede it with Ctrl-V.

Comment: He wants to leave the _command line_, not _insert mode_, but the mapping is almost identical: `:cnoremap`.

Comment: @Ingo Karkat: OK, thanks. I never leave command mode except when finishing the command, so despite his words, I assumed he meant to leave insert mode.

Comment: Although not relevant answer, you helped me fix my problem with remaping Esc to something more reachable :)